# My account ban does not seem salvageable; what should I do?

Tags: discussion, post-ban

I have 28 posts that are alive and 3 posts that are removed. Among the 28 posts, 3 posts are negative with each being -1, -1, -2.

Those are understandable because my questions were really noobish, because I was a novice on the topic, but I don't think that being a novice is downvote worthy. Still I can understand.

However, those three cannot be salvaged because the topics simply sound really dumb to many people.

Now for the three that were removed. I don't know why one is removed, but I assume that it is again, because it was really dumb to most. (I was asking if I'm not allowed to call "prepare" twice for MySQL on PHP, but it turns out my error was that I wasn't using backticks.)

The two were because I was asking questions that rely on personal opinions. I didn't realize one was removed (asking about possible frameworks to build surveys from scratch), and today another removed (asking about why IDEs are popular in Java and not in C++) that resulted in my ban.

It seems like I got banned from a misunderstanding, and now I'm stuck in a spot where I don't know how to salvage my account. How should I go around this if my negative-point questions aren't likely to become positive?

Comment: *but I don't think that being a novice is downvote worthy. Still I can understand.* - well no, you grossly misunderstand. The content is downvoted, not the novice.

Comment: "The content is downvoted, not the novice" - That, then, I don't understand. Because among the downvoted content, I genuinely don't notice issues.

Comment: Well that is the true problem then, because the downvotes / lack of upvotes and the ban are not going to just disappear. Many people take the road of asking what they can improve and get plenty of guidance for it. Consider doing that too rather than treating this as if it is unsalvageable.

Comment: Fair point. I'll post another post asking exactly that instead

Comment: There's my post about asking for improvements. Please help me out because atm it seems bleak :(  http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333862/help-on-how-to-improve-my-negative-scored-questions?noredirect=1#comment391470_333862

Comment: You likely weren't banned due to a misunderstanding.  There are conditions as to why anyone is question-banned.

Comment: I meant that I got banned from my misunderstanding of the rules.

Answer (score 0):

It is not unsalvageable, the idea is that the current content is improved. That takes hard work and will take time to be noticed, but it [is not impossible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans). It isn't easy either, though. Content that has already been downvoted especially has a harder time to turn around. What needs to happen is that new voters turn the tide, do not expect existing voters to come back and change their votes. It might still happen, but it is not what you should be aiming for.

People on meta are very willing to provide guidance on how to improve existing posts so its always welcome to ask about that - which [you did](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333862/help-on-how-to-improve-my-negative-scored-questions).

For further understanding of why this happened in the first place, the link that  [πάντα ῥεῖ provided](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th) can tell a whole lot more, as can many other existing meta questions.

Comment: SE team folks seem to believe that in some cases content can't be improved really and they offer [an option to restart at a slower rate](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/234518/165773) for cases like that