# Help on how to improve my negative scored questions

Tags: discussion, post-ban

I am currently post-banned (the detailed explanation can be found here: [My account ban does not seem salvageable; what should I do?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333859/my-account-ban-does-not-seem-salvageable-what-should-i-do?noredirect=1#comment391465_333859)).

Because I don't know how my negative posts can be improved, I'd really appreciate how I can improve my following three negative posts I have. Any suggestion would be great.

[How can you change the file being redirected to while script is still running?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34217889/how-can-you-change-the-file-being-redirected-to-while-script-is-still-running)

[In Node.JS, by doing require('net'), do you not do require('event')?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34058518/in-node-js-by-doing-requirenet-do-you-not-do-requireevent)

[Differences between Javascript and JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37205895/differences-between-javascript-and-jsp)

Comment: Re your third question, rule #1 is: always Google first. Something like `Differences between Javascript and JSP` has plenty of good results out on the Internet

Comment: Well the first 2 questions have a single downvote, which isn't bad.The last question is just very broad, and is something that you can find out with a bit of searching, hence more downvotes.

Comment: Yeah that I realize now which I didn't then. It was a very beginner question that can be searched. But because it was such a novice question I don't know how it can be improved anymore. Those three are the only downvoted questions I have and I have to try to get rid of those to get un-banned :c

Comment: Drop your account. Start a new one. Never look at the old questions again (and whatever you do, don't touch them with your new account). Do it better next time.

Comment: use the checklist: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist

Comment: The Javascript/JSP questions doesn't work well on SO. Generally the SO community isn't at all keen on questions about technology choices, because they are rarely clear-cut: to analyze all the factors affecting the choice, you need a long question and a long answer, and even then the choices are often subjective. But for log redirect question, I think you were just unlucky: some people downvote questions because they think you should know the answer without asking, which is lousy behaviour in my view.

Answer (score 6):

[Related post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users).

My point of view on your profile out of 28 questions:

- 9 are upvoted.
- 6 are 0 score, 0 answer.
- 7 are 0 score with accepted answer.
- 2 question have valid answers but are not accepted.
- 4 are negatively scored.

You can at least work on 15 questions to make them better.

You're focusing on your negatively scored answer, which makes me think that once again you didn't take the necessary time to read the links like the help center one about the [question-bans](https://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans) which state:

> Begin by fixing your existing questions: they should be clear,
>   specific and on-topic.
>
> **Edit *all* of your questions**, paying special attention to those that
>   score 0 or less.

See [this comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276347/how-do-zero-score-questions-impact-a-question-ban?rq=1#comment115674_276360) to get why 0 score questions have an impact.

Comment: how about my last question?

Comment: @rupinderjeet47 I assume the bold text invalidating the proper usage and the sentence about you having problem with documentation are likely to bring a downvote as a RTFM signal. (that and probably the fact  you give the impression you don't care about how an OS is supposed to work). I didn't vote because coming from meta, but your question as stated is far from respectful of helpers and for all stated above unlikely to help anyone in the future, so it worth a downvote in my opinion.

Comment: OP also has "peer pressure", although several months ago.